# Убрать скроллинг вверх при router.push

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня есть родительский компонент, и в нём дочерний. Родительский статичен, дочерний в зависимости от route меняет содержимое, по сути router-view. И проблема в том, что когда делаешь router.push (к другому дочернему компоненту), то происходить скроллинг вверх, как будто страница открылась другая. Можно ли убрать этот scrollToTop? А то это весьма не удобно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалось найти решение. У router есть обработчик scrollBehavior, в нём можно сделать return false и тогда скролла не будет!

```
scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (to.name === 'Show Offer' || from.name === 'Show Offer') {
            return false;
        }
        return { y: 0 };
    },
```